# how is the behaviour of webservice in infopath?

Tags: web-services, infopath-2007

I have webservice in asp.net. it having the webmethod with return type as bool. I am inserting the record from infopath repeating table to xml file using my web method `InsertRecord()`. this is boolean type method. it returns true in insert record successful else returns false. but how to get return value in infopath.

Comment: i am using infopath 2007

Comment: Then my answer is perfectly relevant :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For InfoPath 2007 [MSDN states](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb852081%28v=office.12%29.aspx): “For a submit operation, you can set the XML payload, but you cannot retrieve the XML response.” For InfoPath 2010 I can't see a similar article on MSDN.

You have two options:

1. redesign the web service to throw an exception in case of failure which will lead to a SOAP fault, and in turn a submit failure in InfoPath;
2. use custom code to call the web service and submit the data yourself.